# Segmentation fault on std::list.begin()

Tags: c++, iterator, containers, coredump

I have initialized an iterator and assigned the iterator to the beginning of list to iterate through the container in the following manner.

```
std::list<ptr*> list_var;
std::list<ptr*>::iterator iter = NULL;
iter = list_var.begin();
```

But mysteriously,Segmentation fault happens when line 3 {iter = list_var.begin();} is executed.
What possibly could lead to a crash at this point ?

Comment: *Many things.* Some other part of your code may have corrupted the heap, or triggered undefined behavior in another way. That bug may only be the manifestation of a problem that occurs elsewhere.

Comment: Embrace C++11. Use `nullptr`, not `NULL`. Don't assign either to your iterator instance. Also, `auto` keeps iterator code neat: `auto iter = list_var.begin();`

Comment: Please show some actual code, the code you have in the question shouldn't even compile!

Answer (score 2):

With the declaration and initialization of the iterator:

```
std::list<ptr*>::iterator iter = NULL;
```

you forget that here you're not actually assigning to where the iterator *points* to (which is nowhere), but to the actual iterator *object* instance. In fact, that code should not even compile! It shouldn't compile because the compiler can't convert an integer value (which is what `NULL` is in C++, it's simply `0`) to an `std::list<ptr*>::iterator` object.

Comment: So you think `iter` is trying to free the `NULL` pointer it was constructed with? In that case, shouldn't the copy constructor throw instead?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Well the iterator doesn't *point* anywhere, so what should it assign `NULL` to?

Comment: That's why I said the copy constructor (it looks like copy construction is taking place, not assignment) should throw when passed `NULL` if it doesn't support it. Of course, if it doesn't, anything goes.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi There's no requirement that iterators should throw. Besides, the point is moot anyway since the code provided by the OP is not compilable.